# How to remove EventArgs from the event handler?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

EventArgs need to pass object's arguments to the event handler. But I don't want to pass arguments. How to remove `class C : EventArgs {}`?

```
using System;
class D
{    
    public event EventHandler eventEH;
    public void someMethod(C e) // class C are used here, that's why I can't to remove it
    {    
        EventHandler objEH = eventEH;
        if (objEH != null)
            objEH(this, e);
    }
}

class C : EventArgs {} // Need to remove

class B
{
    public B(D objD)
        { objD.eventEH += new EventHandler(display); }

    void display(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { Console.WriteLine("display"); }
}

class A
{
    static int Main()
    {
        D objD = new D();
        B objB = new B(objD);
        C objC = new C();
        objD.someMethod(objC);        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the signature of OnBallInPlay?

Comment: @LordTakkera Yes, already done

Comment: Why do you want to remove `EventArgs`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because I don't use it in this case. Maybe it's incorrect, but I just starting to learn events

Comment: For my custom events, I almost never need event args, and so use Actions (see my answer). I wouldn't say removing them is a problem.

Comment: @dima - The `EventHandler` "pattern" in .NET has been their from day one. It's something that most developers use without thinking twice about it. If you choose to use something else you might confuse others an make your code harder to maintain if you work on a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EventHandler delegate looks like:

```
void EventHandler(object, EventArgs);
```

However, events can be on whatever delegate you want.

If you really want the "C" object in your event, just declare the event as:

```
public event Action<C> EventEH.
```

Otherwise you can just use `Action`. Then you can remove the inheritance, etc. You also don't need the EventHandler object at this point, just giving the function name will work fine. Your final code would look like:

```
using System;
class D
{    
    public event Action<C> eventEH;
    public void someMethod(C e)
    {    
        EventHandler objEH = eventEH;
        if (objEH != null)
            objEH(e);
    }
}

class C {}

class B
{
    public B(D objD)
        { objD.eventEH += display; }

    void display(C cObject)
        { Console.WriteLine("display"); }
}

class A
{
    static int Main()
    {
        D objD = new D();
        B objB = new B(objD);
        C objC = new C();
        objD.someMethod(objC);        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or, without "C":

```
using System;
class D
{    
    public event Action eventEH;
    public void someMethod()
    {    
        EventHandler objEH = eventEH;
        if (objEH != null)
            objEH();
    }
}

class B
{
    public B(D objD)
        { objD.eventEH += display; }

    void display()
        { Console.WriteLine("display"); }
}

class A
{
    static int Main()
    {
        D objD = new D();
        B objB = new B(objD);
        objD.someMethod();        
        return 0;
    }
}
```